# Which streaming method is used by ExoPlayer for Standalone container formats?

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

Documentation of `ExoPlayer` says that it supports adaptive streaming(`DASH`, `SmoothStreaming`, `HLS`). I just want to know, which streaming method is used by `ExoPlayer` for "Standalone container formats" like mp4,m4a etc? Does it uses progressive streaming? I am implementing `ExoPlayer` in android app.

Comment: Yes, just http progressive downloads, and http range requests.

Comment: How to use http range request with exoplayer to specify range?

Comment: You don't. Exoplayer does it automatically when necessary.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks.